Unterschiede zwischen Modalwörtern, die auf -weise auslauten, den entsprechenden Adjektiven und substantivischen Konstruktionen „in ... Weise‟
Folgendes steht in einem Grammatik Lehrbuch:

In der Regel jedoch müssen die Modalwörter auf -weise sowohl von den entsprechenden Bildungen ohne -weise als auch von substantivischen Ausdrücken mit „in... Weise‟ deutlich getrennt werden (auch in der Bedeutung).
Aus: Deutsche Gramamtik: Ein Handbuch für den Ausländerunterricht von Joachim Buscha und Gerhard Helbig, Langenscheid

z.B. Er handelt klug — Er handelt in kluger Weise — Er handelt klugerweise. (Adv., objektiv — Adv., objektiv — Modalwort, subjektiv)
Also verstehe ich irgendwie, dass die Formen in verschiedenen Zusammenhängen verwendet werden, aber die Bedeutungsunterschiede gar nicht. Deutet das Modalwort vielmehr eine persönliche Ansicht an?
Danke schön

Nehmen wir an, dass die Handlung darin besteht, dass Herr Müller nicht versucht, mit dem Bürgermeister der Gemeinde eine gute Beziehung herzustellen, sondern mit dem Büroleiter der Gemeinde, den der ist im Gegensatz zum Bürgermeister ein fix angestellter Beamter, während der Bürgermeister alle paar Jahre neu gewählt wird und wechseln kann.
Was bedeuten nun die drei Sätze in diesem Kontext?

Er handelt klug.
Das bedeutet, dass das Herstellen einer guten Beziehung zum Büroleiter eine kluge Handlung ist.

Er handelt klugerweise.
Das bedeutet, dass der Grund, warum Herr Müller sich für diese Handlung entscheiden hat, die Klugheit des Herrn Müller ist.

Er handelt in kluger Weise.
Das bedeutet, dass die Art und Weise, wie Herr Müller versucht, eine Freundschaft mit dem Büroleiter herzustellen, klug ist.



Das macht es eindeutig, danke sehr! Und danke fürs Bearbeiten :) @hubert


Er handelt in kluger Weise.

Er handelt in einer Weise, die klug ist. Es geht hier also darum, wie er etwas tut.

Er handelt klugerweise.

Er handelt, und das ist klug. Hier geht es darum, dass er etwas tut. Anstatt es nicht zu tun.
Man kann sogar beides kombinieren:

Er handelt klugerweise in kluger Weise.

Er handelt in einer Weise, die klug ist, und das ist klug.

Er handelt freundlicherweise in schneller Weise.

Er handelt in einer Weise, die schnell ist, und das ist freundlich.

Ah, das ist sehr hilfreich! Danke Ihnen vielmals :) @janka
